# Is this integral 0 or $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Given two measure space, $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ with lebesgue measure $\mu$, and $(Y,\mathcal{B},c)$ with counting measure $c$,and assuming $X=Y=[0,1]$. Now consider the integral over diagnosis on product measure space $X\times Y$,(i.e. $\Delta=\{(x,y)|x=y,x\in X,y\in Y\}$).

Its iterated integrals are different, then my question is how to evaluate the following integral:
$$
\int_{X\times Y}\chi_\Delta d(\mu\times c)
$$

Comment: "integral over *diagnosis* on product measure space?" I am not familiar with the term *diagnosis* in this context, though that might just be a fault of my own.

Comment: @par I think he meant to write diagonal, as specified in the parentheses at the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

By definition the product measure is the outer measure defined using covers by countable unions of "rectangles". If $$\Delta\subset\bigcup_jA_j\times B_j$$then it's not hard to show that $$\sum\mu(A_j)c(B_j)=\infty;$$hence $(\mu\times c)(\Delta)=\infty$.